# Use Japanese Handwriting on a tablet with Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, tablet, handwriting

I have Windows 7 Professional 64 bit on a Tablet I recently bought. I would like to use handwritten Japanese without having to purchase the Windows 7 Ultimate Edition. Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just stumble this website today.
You might want to check it out. It's free for download and you can install MUI and LIP without upgrading to Windows7 Ultimate.

http://www.froggie.sk/usage.html

Comment: yeah, forgot to mention that I found that option as well :)

Answer (score 2):

While there are packs to allow limited language integration of the GUI, to my knowledge there's no way to carry this over to the tablet features.  You either need to purchase Windows 7 Ultimate (easiest done through Windows Anytime Upgrade) or you need to purchase (I say purchase because I doubt you'll find a good one for free) a 3rd party Japanese handwriting recognition software.

Comment: One interesting thing I can't explain:
I installed the English version of Win7Pro, with German Regional Settings and Keyboard Setting. Initially, I had the German dictionary for handwriting. As I only got this tablet today, I had to install loads of updates. Before some of the last updates, the German dictionary is suddenly gone and only the English dictionary remains. So apparently the dictionary CAN change, but I would want my German dictionary back, any idea how?

Comment: I addition to that, apparently I can't use the Anytime Upgrade to upgrade Win7Pro to Win7Ultimate. At least WAU tells me I can't upgrade, and at least at Amazon I don't see of those Upgrade Options.